# make every mount a new folder in dropzone js upload directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

im using `dropzone.js` in my project to upload articles image.
for example all of article images will upload here:

```
www.site.com/images/uploads/.... .jpg
```

my dropzone usage

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"});
$("div#myId").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

i want automatically make a folder with (date) name every month in `uploads` folder and upload that mount images into this folder.

what can i do? 
tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, You need to create a cron job in your server to create a new folder each month.

```
0 0 1 * * /usr/bin/mkdir /yourDir/$(date +%Y%m)
```

Or by running server code to create folder like this in PHP:

```
mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0755);
```

And then you can set your dropZone code to be like this:

```
 var today = new Date();
 var currentMonth = today.getFullYear() + '' + (today.getMonth()+1);
 var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post/" + currentMonth});
```

Note: make sure to set truth timezone for client and server. like get time at UTC....etc

Comment: can we do this way? : check the (today) folder exist, when upload starts and if it exist, upload images into that folder and if dose not exist, create the folder

Comment: Yes you can that..., by using server side language

Comment: but i think your way is better. because when number of folders are very much, my way should check (today) folder exist of not. (between hundreds of folders)